# PHP framework similar Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I uses Zend in my project: it does not need MVC, but it uses Zend classes like Zend_Translate or Zend_Validate.
I should not create Zend environment for validate few HTTP request params I just need Form and Validators.
Zend is more class library then framework. 
I'm looking the similar framework for PHP 5.3. 
What can you suggest me?

Comment: *(overview)* http://www.phpframeworks.com/ and http://www.php-frameworks.net/

Comment: What's with the "not a real question" votes? Does this sound like not a real question? Find a duplicate if you want to close.

Comment: @Josh K: If it is a real question, then what is being asked?

Comment: @GregS: "What can you suggest me?"   Seems like a question to me :)

Comment: @Josh the framework question has been answered a gazillion times. If the OP is too lazy to use the search function, then I am too lazy to find a duplicate.

Comment: phpframeworks.com is a useless link. hasn't been updated in a long time.

Comment: @GregS: He's asking for a set of PHP libraries similar to Zend.

Comment: The key feature of framework what I'm looking for is PHP 5.3 and "class library" style.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at:

[Kohana 3](http://kohanaframework.org/)

> Kohana is an elegant HMVC PHP5
>   framework that provides a rich set of
>   components for building web
>   applications.
>
> It requires very little configuration,
>   fully supports UTF-8 and i18n, and
>   provides many of the tools that a
>   developer needs within a highly
>   flexible system. The integrated class
>   auto-loading, cascading filesystem,
>   highly consistent API, and easy
>   integration with vendor libraries make
>   it viable for any project, large or
>   small.

Comment: I meant kohana 3.0 not older version.

Comment: I downloaded Kohana 3.0.7 it does not uses PHP 5.3 namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

look for loosely-coupled frameworks. [php fatfree framework](http://bcosca.github.com/fatfree/) is one.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:

- Agavi http://www.agavi.org
- CakePHP http://cakephp.org
- CodeIgniter http://codeigniter.com
- symfony http://www.symfony-project.org

Answer (score 1):

I agree that Zend is more like CPAN for Perl, collection of classes with minimum dependencies. If you want to take more advantage of dependencies you need a high-level framework. Preferable with User Interface support.

http://agiletoolkit.org/intro

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [YII Framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [SingularCore](http://singularcore.com)

Answer (score 0):

Zend is a loosely coupled framework. I'm not sure about your problem, but the components I have worked with (like Zend_View) are completely independent of MVC stack.

Can you explain more about them problem?